# Android Bluetooth Communication Type?

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port

I would like to know what the communication method is for android bluetooth communication.
My code basically follows the developer guide here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html
If I follow this guide and read/write data from/into devices? What would be the communication type? I searched the web and it looked like a serial port communication, RS 232. Is this correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is serial ... just like RS232 ... and I think you can even use RS232 libraries (with minor customization) with blue tooth com ports